# want to add expand and collapse functionality to a dynamically generated file as parent node

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

### im developing a webpage,in that im displaying a testsuite file as a parentnode and tescases which are in testsuite file are child nodes.. im adding checkboxes to the parent node aswell as child nodes..what i want is, i want to add expand and collapse option to the parent node..bedefault when page loads it should be collapsed,when i click on that parent node it should be ellapsed..plzz i tried it with many ways but i couldnot get.. any help would be appreciated.. thanks in advance

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

     //ddtreemenu.createTree(treeid, enablepersist, opt_persist_in_days (default is 1))


     function getAlldetails()
         {
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

//alert("hello");
//alert("ok");
//Create a asynchronous GET request
xmlhttp.open("GET",
        "http://localhost:8080/sample/Husky?action=profilevalues", true);
//alert("checkig");
xmlhttp.send();
//alert("after send request");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {


    //alert("ready state:::"+xmlhttp.status);

    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var response = xmlhttp.responseText;

            var data = eval("(" + response + ")");//json data get
            //alert(data);
            var rootinfo=data.rootdirectory;
            var dir=rootinfo.root;
            //alert(rootinfo.root);
            var allfiles=data.listfiles;
            //alert(allfiles);

             // Make the list itself which is a <ul>
             var listElement = document.getElementById("treemenu1");
             listElement.innerHTML=dir;
             var breakinfoone=document.createElement("br");
             sessionStorage.setItem("filetwo","");

             listElement.appendChild(breakinfoone);


            for ( var i = 0; i<allfiles.length; i++) {
                var subobj = allfiles[i];
                var id = subobj.singlefile;

            var labelinfo=document.createElement("label");
            var breakinfo=document.createElement("br");
            labelinfo.innerHTML="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"+id;
            var ptworkinfo=document.createElement("input");   
                ptworkinfo.innerHTML="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"+id;
                ptworkinfo.type="checkbox";
                ptworkinfo.id="cbox"+i;
                ptworkinfo.value=id;

                listElement.appendChild(ptworkinfo);
                listElement.appendChild(labelinfo);
                listElement.appendChild(breakinfo);
                ptworkinfo.onchange = function(event) {
                     if(document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("id")).checked)
                     {
                        alert(this.getAttribute("value"));
                        sessionStorage.setItem("filetwo", this.getAttribute("value"));
                     }
                     else
                      {
                            sessionStorage.setItem("filetwo","");
                      }
                 }                      
            }   
        }           
    }
};
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a CSS class e.g. "collapsed" which would hide list items in the list element. Then toggle the class on click on a list element:

```
listElement.onclick = function() {
  this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
}
```

Js fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/gh424/2/

Of course clicks on elements inside the list will trigger click on the list itself and it will toggle. If it is not desired behavior then think of wrapping the list into div e.g.:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="toggler">Toggles the lsit</div>
    <ul class="collapsed">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating you parent nodes and child nodes in ajax call success.
So you have to attach event only after they are added into DOM.

OR

You can use jQuery "On" method to your parent nodes.

> $( "body" ).on( "click", "parent_elements_selector", function() {
>
> > // toggle parent class
>
> });

Comment: If you are not using jQuery then add
ptworkinfo.onclick = function() {
                 if(ptworkinfo.className.indexOf(" expand") == -1) {
                   ptworkinfo.className = ptworkinfo.className + " expand ";
                 }
                  else {
                    ptworkinfo.className.replace(/\bexpand\b/,'');
                  }
               }
and this expand class should expand your childnode.

Comment: Can u explain it clearly? there className indicates which class name??